# Relocating text with js code

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to reverse the order of the words (e.g. `25/0`) in a string.

As following example:

```
In Normal:        25/0 24/5 23/9 23/7 23/9
After Relocation: 23/9 23/7 23/9 24/5 25/0  // I want this my output
```

How can done it by jQuery or javascript? 
Please tell me in case it in http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: @Jacob, after your revision, the question makes even less sense for me. He just wants inverse order apparently.

Comment: @Jacob My bad, I didn't see you only edited the title. It's just that the former first statement in the question seemed even more senseless after your edit than the first time I've read it (which you didn't modify).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See http://jsfiddle.net/A8End/

```
var text="25/0 24/5 23/9 23/7 23/9";
alert(text.split(' ').reverse().join(' '));
```

You can `split` the text in order to have an array. Then you can easily `reverse` it and `join` it to a string again.